# Ng-Repeat and creating new child scopes

Tags: angularjs

I'm just trying to understand 
if np-repeat creates a new child scope in each iteration, then why this code sets the variable in the parent scope and not in the child scope:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('WorldCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.population = 7000;
            $scope.countries = [
                {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
                {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8},
            ];
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='WorldCtrl'>
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <span ng-init="country.name='Egypt'"></span>
        {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}
</li>
  
 <hr>
    World's population: {{population}} millions {{countries}}
</div>
```

Expected output:

```
 Egypt has population of 63.1
 Egypt has population of 61.8
```

```
World's population: 7000 millions [{"name":"France","population":63.1},{"name":"United Kingdom","population":61.8}]
```

Comment: I'm confused; what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I've edited the question, please have a look

Comment: It sets `country.name` in the parent scope because `coutry` is read from JS prototype chain, it is not found in this object, so taken from the parent, and then `name` is is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is because as an object, you are passing references and not copies of the model. The ng-repeat is creating a variable `country` which is a reference of the current iteration object of the array `countries`, and so you are altering the property of a referenced object, not a copy.

Comment: Ahhhh how I missed that!!! if it was:  $scope.countries = [
                'France',
                'United Kingdom'
            ];  then it would work like I imagined. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` does indeed create its own scope which overshadows variables defined in the parent scope.  That is to say if the parent scope had a property called `country`, you would not be able to access it in the `ng-repeat` template.

However, the `country` property that is created in the child scope is made of references to properties in the parent scope.  This is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.

You could get around this by overwriting the entire `country` property instead of using the prototype chain.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('WorldCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.population = 7000;
            $scope.countries = [
                {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
                {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8},
            ];
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='WorldCtrl'>
<li ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <span ng-init="country = {name: 'Egypt', population: country.population}"></span>
        {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}
</li>
  
 <hr>
    World's population: {{population}} millions {{countries}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just had an Ah-HA moment